# Centering ListView's empty view in parent

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with an empty view set as a view I create programmatically. I'd like to have it centered both horizontally and vertically. I found this code while searching how to do that on google.:

```
TextView myTv = new TextView(getActivity());
myTv.setText("No results");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
myTv.setLayoutParams(param);
myTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
((RelativeLayout) mScheduleListView.getParent()).addView(myTv, 0);

mScheduleListView.setEmptyView(myTv);
```

The XML layout for the fragment holding the ListView above looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScheduleFragment" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/mScheduleListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout shows, but not centered. I have no idea why it doesn't work. I tried messing with the `LayoutParams` and change them to `MATCH_PARENT` but apparently that wasn't the problem.
If so what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: you want to show "No results" when list is empty?????

Comment: Yes. It shows "No results" but I want it to be centered

Comment: Why dont you create another Textview in xml which is centered and display it when the list is empty

Answer (score 2):

Set `Textview` Gravity in Center

Help Code:

```
myTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

write this code in your layout..It may works..

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Apparently `param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, -1)` works.
Thank to the documentation I figured out that the value for `true` is -1.
All solutions I read about centering a view suggested `true` was actually 0 (for the `addRule` method).